# "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" during updating non unique field

Tags: postgresql

We are trying to move our application to new postgresql cluster.

during doing that we noticed that application threw exception like that:

```
[2017-06-02 14:43:34,530] ........ (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "items_url"
DETAIL:  Key (url)=(http://www.domainname.ru/ap_module/content/article/400-professional/140-professional/11880) already exists.
 [SQL: 'UPDATE items SET status=%(status)s WHERE items.id IN ....
```

it's very strange because:

- the application writes to `items` fields, not `items_url`. `items_url` is indexes by `items`, actually
- `UPDATE` only changes status fields that hasn't flag `unique` and also it is not a `primary key`.

table items:

```
id              | integer                     | not null default nextval(('public.items_id_seq'::text)::regclass)
 ctime           | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
 pubdate         | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
 resource_id     | integer                     | not null default 0
 url             | text                        |
 title           | text                        |
 description     | text                        |
 body            | text                        |
 status          | smallint                    | not null default 0
 image           | text                        |
 orig_id         | integer                     | not null default 0
 mtime           | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
 checksum        | text                        |
 video_url       | text                        |
 audio_url       | text                        |
 content_type    | smallint                    | default 0
 author          | text                        |
 video           | text                        |
 fulltext_status | smallint                    | default 0
 summary         | text                        |
 image_id        | integer                     |
 video_id        | integer                     |
 priority        | smallint                    |

Indexes:
    "items_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "items_url" UNIQUE, btree (url)
    "items_resource_id" btree (resource_id)
    "ndx__items__ctime" btree (ctime)
    "ndx__items__image" btree (image_id)
    "ndx__items__mtime" btree (mtime)
    "ndx__items__pubdate" btree (pubdate)
    "ndx__items__video" btree (video_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "items_fkey1" FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES images(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
    "items_fkey2" FOREIGN KEY (video_id) REFERENCES videos(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NUL
```

Well, the question is why it happens and how can I troubleshoot this?
Thank you.

**UPD1:**
I tried to reproduce it on 9.4. - reproduced

Played with client_encoding. Encoding everywhere is the same.

Comment: Start by adding the definition for the table to the question. (BTW: are there any triggers defined for the table?)

Comment: ... including keys and indexes, please ...

Comment: ... plus the actual offending statement, please. (the generated SQL can be found in the postgres logfile) (the database structure can be obtained by `pg_dump --schema-only db_name` )

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX items_url ON items USING btree (url);

Comment: UPDATE items SET status=1 WHERE items.id IN (
95610506, 95610560, 95610505, 95610561, …..
)
;

Comment: Also it happens when the app does an insert https://pastebin.com/axMjcGYc

Comment: Well it seems odd. Either a trigger-thing, or a corrupt index, maybe the COLLATE for the text column (default := use database collation) (or the encoding at the client side?) or *maybe* even a bug. (version?)

Comment: As you can see there are no triggers, index is in ok state. The new version where we are going to move `9.6.3-1PGDG.rhel7` , old version `postgresql94-server-9.4.8`  `COLLATE` is really different on ours systems. I'll make some research about it. thank you for the hint.

Comment: Sorry, I lied to you. `COLLATE`s are the same.

Comment: I suggest you drop unique index, execute update query and see what duplicates you have after that. It must be updated as some side effect. There is also one possibility. If check of your constraints is deferred they are checked at the end of transaction, so it may be consequence of some query before this.